# Does isopropyl alcohol have a similar affect as dipropylene glycol regarding absorption?

Tags: solutions

I am an aromatherapist and am making essential oil reed diffusers.  Do you know if isopropyl alcohol has a similar affect in absorption as dipropylene glycol?